# Singleton objective c clarification

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

as I continue my studies the book implemented a singleton. 
I understood the reason why use it but I just wanted some clarification regarding the code.

```
+ (BNRItemStore *)defaultStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *defaultStore = nil;
    if(!defaultStore)
        defaultStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return defaultStore;
}
```

In the line `static BNRItemStore * defaultStore = nil;` until the return statement.
My question is; all the time that I call this class, `[[BNRItemStore defaultStore] someMethod];` in another class or part of the app, the defaultStore variable will be set to nil?

Cheers

Comment: Note that the method you're using to create a singleton is **not** threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks, I know. It is just an example of implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that the `static` keyword has two effects.  One is that it makes that variable exist before the method is called, and persist after it returns, so that it will be available for the next call.  The other effect is more subtle -- the "assignment" that initializes the static variable is executed when the code is loaded, not when the method is called.  So it does not get reinitialized on every call.

But since the variable exists "outside" of the method, it's name should be unique -- don't use the same name in another singleton in this class or another one.

Comment: The variable's name is local to the function scope.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe -- I wouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

That's the initializer of a variable with static storage duration. The value will be set when the executable is loaded into memory.

Note that its not necessary to explicitly set the value to nil as all variables with static storage duration are automatically set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

For function-static variables the line

```
static BNRItemStore *defaultStore = nil;
```

is not an *assignment*. Rather, it is *static initialization*, which happens only once - the first time the code goes through your function. In subsequent invocations the value will not be `nil`, because you assign a non-nil value to it.

Your implementation is safe in single-threaded environments. For concurrent environments you would need to add some form of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are initialized just the one time when the function/method is first called.  After that, you can basically pretend the line doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Apple recommends something like the following

```
+ (BNRItemStore *)defaultStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *defaultStore = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t done;
    dispatch_once(&done,
                  ^{ defaultStore = [BNRItemStore alloc]init];});
    return defaultStore;
}
```

The above code assumes ARC - If not using ARC you would have to define do nothing retain, release, autorelease,  and dealloc methods.

Comment: This code up here have the same effect in the way I use the singleton?